# Can NSIS scripts add 2 integers & 'OR' a StrCmp

Tags: installation, nsis

**Is it possible to add 2 numbers together in Native NSIS(not using libraries)?**

```
Var hasVersion9    # values will either be 0 or 1
Var hasVersion10
Var hasVersion9Or10

IntCpy $hasVersion9Or10 hasVersion9+hasVersion10
(IntCmp $hasVersion9Or10 1 OR IntCmp $hasVersion9Or10 2) doThis doThat
```

**Is it also possible to perform an 'Or' operation in a string comparision?**

```
StrCmp $myVar ("1" OR "11") doThis doThat
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [IntOp](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#intop) for number operations and the [logiclib](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Include/LogicLib.nsh) for if/orif